# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el eje X de un plot sean las fechas?

Tags: matlab

Estoy sacando los TLE de la ISS y quiero plotear la altura en función del tiempo. Tengo las alturas de los últimos dos años en un vector y las fechas en una matriz, pero no sé cómo hacer para que en el plot me aparezca la fecha en el eje X. Por ejemplo:

```
Matriz de fecha:

Año mes día hora minuto segundo

2020 3 5 18 45 8

2020 10 6 21 8 55
```

```
Vector de alturas:
(Km)

415

389
```

Comment: Hola @Julio. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla. Además, puede consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas aumentar tus posibilidades de obtener ayuda. También, puede consultar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que crear el vector x como datetime y luego usar el plot

```
t = datetime(2014,6,28) + calweeks(0:9);
y = rand(1,10);
plot(t,y);
```